# Python - How to transform sqlite3 based module into non-blocking mode with asyncio

Tags: sqlite, async-await

I am translating a custom library into asyncio mode.

When I tries to get a cursour it returns a coroutine. 
How to transform the coroutine into cursor object?

Here are some code I am translating to asyncio.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#  sqlite01.py
import os
import asyncio
import sqlite3
import time
class SQLite():

    def __init__(self,DB='./static/Clientes.db'):
        print("sqlite01>Current Directory:%s" %os.getcwd())
        self.DB=DB

    def GetCursor(self):
         with sqlite3.connect(self.DB) as db:
             return db.cursor()

    async def GetCursor_Async(self):
         async with sqlite3.connect(self.DB) as db:
             return db.cursor()

    def CreateHTML(self,CURSOR,OPT=None):
        para =[]
        for row in CURSOR.execute('''SELECT * FROM cliente ORDER BY nome'''):
            para.append( "<option value=\""+str(row[0])+"\">"+str(row[0])+"</option>")
        return para
```

How I am testing this module

```
import sqlite01
SQL = sqlite01.SQLite()

#Blocking mode
Cursor = SQL.GetCursor()
Result = SQL.CreateHTML(Cursor)
type(Result)
<class 'list'>

#NON-BLOCKING ERROR
CURSOR = SQL.GetCursor_Async()
SQL.CreateHTML(CURSOR)
>>> 

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/felipe/workspace/nwi_prtg/codes/sqlite01.py", line 23, in CreateHTML
    for row in CURSOR.execute('''SELECT * FROM cliente ORDER BY nome'''):
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'execute'
```